# iphone touchesbegan

Tags: iphone

I am using `touchesBegan:`.

I touch an object and drag-and-drop it to some other place, but I also want to make a copy of it on its original. That is, after touching and dragging, there should be a copy of it at its original position.

Below is my code:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch=[[event allTouches]anyObject];
    CGPoint location=[touch locationInView:touch.view];
    image1.center=location;
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{       
    [self touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: what is your questions exactly? Please rephrase it!

Comment: ok i will explain in detail, i am having an imageview named as image1 on that i am adding touchesbegan when we touch the image1 we are able to move it anywhere on screen but the thing i want is to retain a copy of the image at its original position and another copy we can drag anywhere on screen. Hope i made it clear this time.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of moving image1 create and image2 (in `touchesBegan`) and move it (in `touchesMoved`)

You have to get touches from the superview of the object you want to move I believe.

You didn't show what image1 is, hence nobody can tell certainly how to copy that.

Comment: image 1 is any image , here i had taken an imageview backgroundcolor red and named it as image1.